# Can't install M2Crypto into Linux mint Rafaela

Tags: python, linux, swig, m2crypto

I'm trying to install `M2Crypto` library with `pip` inside a `virtualenv`, but I just can't make it work,

I have done `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and `sudo apt-et install python-m2crypto` already, they are in the system

Also tried installing `pip install pyopenssl`

These are last lines of my traceback (it's way too long):

```
  SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘dsa_get_g’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:6220:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘dsa_get_pub’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:6228:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘dsa_get_priv’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:6236:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘dsa_check_key’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:6489:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘dsa_check_pub_key’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:6493:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘dsa_keylen’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:6497:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘x509_name_get_der’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:7313:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘ecdsa_sig_get_r’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8127:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘ecdsa_sig_get_s’:
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8131:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

`I also have`swig installed no my system, any ideas on what it could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show error not by warning message.

Comment: Could you please file an issue ticket on https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/ and attach please complete output of the command ``python setup.py clean build install`` together with the version of Python, OpenSSL, and swig, please?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, it was a version issue, just ran:

```
pip install M2Crypto==0.24.0
```

Thank You